# HTML 5 Section / Aside margin problem

Tags: css, html

I'm tearing my hair out on this one. I've already set a reset stylesheet which I was hoping would handle everything and set all the margins and paddings to 0 (redundant, I know), but if you'll look at the [result](http://jsfiddle.net/nojj02/BzCsj/embedded/result/) of this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nojj02/BzCsj/), my `section` tag won't touch the side of my `aside` tag even though the browsers all indicate that there are no margins or paddings present.

Interestingly, it works in IE 7, all other browsers fail miserably. =/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They aren't touching because you've set `aside` and `section` to be `inline-block` elements:

```
nav, section, aside {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

With `inline-block` elements, whitespace in the HTML becomes significant.

One solution is to remove the whitespace between your `aside` and `section`:

http://jsfiddle.net/BzCsj/2/

```
<aside id="sidebar">asd
</aside><section id="main">test
</section>
```

Another solution is to switch from `display: inline-block` to `float: left`. I've done this here with inline CSS for simplicity: http://jsfiddle.net/BzCsj/4/

Comment: One thing i'd add is, he is mixing `px` and `em`. Stick with one unit - my unit of preference is `em` due to the nice scaling - but he must use `em` for EVERYTHING - borders, padding, margins, widths, text, everything.

Comment: Wow. Thanks. That's something new for me. I've been inline-blocking everything since forever and I've seen this happen a few times before. Guess that answers all my questions. @Myles, Thanks for the tip, I haven't touched the CSS that much though. Most of it is the default from ASP.NET MVC 3